# Why does a basic Drupal view return no results

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I am starting out with views and I wrote an extremely simple view which really just filters if the node is published and if it is of type banner. In preview and when I try to print the view I get no results. When I search through my content and filter by type banner and published, I get 3 results (in /content/node/overview). I must be doing something basic and stupid, any suggestions for how I can figure out what I have done wrong?

I am starting out with views and I wrote an extremely simple view which really just filters if the node is published and if it is of type banner. In preview and when I try to print the view I get no results. When I search through my content and filter by type banner and published, I get 3 results (in /content/node/overview). I must be doing something basic and stupid, any suggestions for how I can figure out what I have done wrong?

View:
http://www.randomcrapilike.com/test/view_capture.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried creating a block view and then seeing if it outputs properly in the block region on the front end?

Comment: Yeah, I'm curious as to whether this is an issue with the non-standard 'slideshow' display type.

Comment: I also have my money on the slideshow view style not working in preview mode. This is a common problem with styles that use JavaScript, as the necessary JavaScript wasn't included on the initial page load.

Answer (score 1):

A few troubleshooting steps based on your screenshot...

- Try including the node ID in the fields section to make sure the issue isn't with your CCK fields.
- Try a different display type than 'slideshow' to make sure the issue isn't with that (non-standard) display type.
- Try taking the preview query and running it directly against your database. Do you get any results or error messages?